# I have a stored procedure in redshift and I have to convert it into snowflake procedure. How to deal with IN,OUT AND INOUT parameters in snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE inner_proc(INOUT a integer, b integer, INOUT c 
    integer)
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
    AS $$
    BEGIN
     a := b * a;
     c := b * c;
    END;
    $$
```

After procedure conversion, in snowflake, it is something like this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE inner_proc
(
    INOUT a,
    b FLOAT,
    INOUT c
)
RETURNS VARCHAR NOT NULL 
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT 
EXECUTE AS CALLER 
AS 
$$
```

But I am getting a syntax error at INOUT c...
Thanks for our help!!

Answer (score 3):

Snowflake uses JavaScript for stored procedures, which supports only input variables and a single return value. To return complex values, you can use an array or variant with JSON return.

```
create or replace procedure foo("a" float, "b" float, "c" float)
returns variant
language javascript
as
$$
    var out = {};
    
    out["a"] = a;
    out["b"] = b;
    out["c"] = c;
    out["d"] = a + b + c;

    return out;
$$;
```

Note that if you want to use lowercase variable names in the stored procedure signature, you must double quote them. Otherwise, Snowflake treats them like other identifiers outside the body of a JavaScript block and implicitly uppercases them. You'll then have to use uppercase variable names inside the JavaScript for the input variables if you don't double quote them.

Also, when you call a stored procedure in Snowflake, you can't use the results in code directly on the call. You can use the syntax `table(result_scan(last_query_id()))` to get to the return value:

```
call foo(1, 2, 3);

select   FOO:a::int as A
        ,FOO:b::int as B
        ,FOO:c::int as C
        ,FOO:d::int as D
from table(result_scan(last_query_id()));
```

You can then use the column "FOO", in the result_scan. The return of a stored procedure is a single column with the same name as the stored procedure. Its value is the return value. You can treat that return value in the column like any other variant type and parse it using the standard Snowflake notation `COLUMN_NAME:jsonProperty::castType`